# double saving from 1 table to another in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, mysqli

I am copying data from 1 table to another in cakephp . The 2 tables are not exactly the same. The issue is that I am copying the data but it is saving every row 2 times. I checked the debug and the save function is causing a double save. I go get the data copied over but it is saved twice in the mysql DB (phpmyadmin)

I am sure it is something simple but I am stuck.

Notice (1024): Element Not Found: Elements\1.ctp [CORE\Cake\View\View.php, line 425]

```
public function copystudent(){  
      $this->loadModel('Guardian');
      $this->loadModel('Studentbak'); 
       $students =$this->Studentbak->find('all',array( 
             'conditions' => array('id >=' => 227  ),
              // 'order' => array('guardian_first_name ASC'),
        'recursive'=>-1
              ));

       foreach ($students as $data):
             $this->Student->create();

        $newdata = array();
            $newdata = array(
                'Student' => array(
                      'student_inactive' => $data['Studentbak']['student_inactive'],
                      'student_enq' => $data['Studentbak']['student_enq'],
                    'student_unallocated' => $data['Studentbak']['student_unallocated'],
                      'first_name' => $data['Studentbak']['first_name'],
                    'last_name' => $data['Studentbak']['last_name'],
                      'school' => $data['Studentbak']['school'],
                    'class_year' => $data['Studentbak']['class_year'],
                      'start_date' => $data['Studentbak']['start_date'],
                    'address_street' => $data['Studentbak']['address_street'],
                      'address_suburb' => $data['Studentbak']['address_suburb'],
                    'address_postcode' => $data['Studentbak']['address_postcode'],
                      'address_state' => $data['Studentbak']['address_state'],
                    'address_lat' => $data['Studentbak']['address_lat'],
                      'address_long' => $data['Studentbak']['address_long'],
                    'student_mobile' => $data['Studentbak']['student_mobile'],
                      'additional_information' => $data['Studentbak']['additional_information'],
                    'tutoring_type_id' => $data['Studentbak']['tutoring_type_id'],
                      'referral_id' => $data['Studentbak']['referral_id'],
                        'referral_info' => $data['Studentbak']['referral_info'],
                    'reference_code' => $data['Studentbak']['reference_code'],
                      'tutor_gender_preference' => $data['Studentbak']['tutor_gender_preference'],
                    'created' => $data['Studentbak']['created'],
                      'modified' => $data['Studentbak']['modified'],
                    'address_billing' => $data['Studentbak']['address_billing'],
                      'is_email_notify' => $data['Studentbak']['is_email_notify'],
                    'acknowledge' => $data['Studentbak']['acknowledge'],
                      'user_id' => 0,
                    'guardian_id' => 0,
                      'has_credit' => $data['Studentbak']['has_credit']
                   ));
debug($newdata); 


            if($this->Student->save($newdata, false)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Data copied'), true);
            }

            endforeach; 
         //   debug($students);  

 }
```

Comment: Do check your $newdata, you are defining it empty each time. also the. try saving $newdata['Studen'];

Comment: i tried what you said and this doesnt work either, still get double saves?

Comment: ok i am still not getting this to work

Answer (score 0):

Please write following code after save

`$this->Student->id = null`

Comment: no that doesnt work and I get the same issues as before.

Comment: Is there a solution to this problem or this isnt the way you save data in cakephp?